# Node JS: File upload Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-upload, formidable

So What I am trying to do is that I am simply uploading Files to A particular folder using nodeJS with the help of Formidable Module, using the following reference.
[File Upload using  nodeJS](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp)

Now, my file gets uploaded to the Folder which I want, but as I am running the command from the CLI, it gives me an error

Here is the **code** that I tried :

```
var http = require('http') ;
var formidable = require('formidable') ;
var fs = require('fs');


http.createServer(function(req, res){
if(req.url == '/fileUpload'){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err,fields,files){
        var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        var newpath = 'C://xampp/htdocs/nodejs/upload/' + files.filetoupload.name;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.write('File Uploaded and Moved !!');
            res.end();
        });
        res.write('File Uploaded');
        res.end();
    });
}
else{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}) ;
    res.write('<form action="fileUpload" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type = "file" name="filetoupload" /><br/>') ;
    res.write('<input type="submit" />') ;
    res.write('</form>') ;
    return res.end() ;
    }
}).listen(8080) ;
```

The **Error** I am getting is :

```
> Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
>     at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:572:17)
>     at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:567:10)
>     at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\upload.js:14:8
>     at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20) Emitted 'error' event at:
>     at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:634:7)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to write after you've closed the stream.

```
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err,fields,files){
        var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        var newpath = 'C://xampp/htdocs/nodejs/upload/' + files.filetoupload.name;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.write('File Uploaded and Moved !!');
            res.end(); // here, remove this end call
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are correct that he is writing after closing the stream, but not at the line you specified. The line you specified is in the callback for fs.rename and will be executed after the second res.end

Comment: then which one to remove ? @r.delic

Comment: got it . @LawrenceCherone .